# swap operations on c++17 string_views seems to be extremely cache inefficient

Tags: string, algorithm, caching, c++17, string-view

I’ve been working on trying to optimise a proprietary algorithm that sorts vectors of string codes base on an internal indexing criteria. The lengths of the codes range from 1 - 32 chars. The algorithm performed a std::swap to move the string into its new location.

```cpp
std::vector<std::string> temp_container(sorting_size+1,"");
for(auto &index_seed : all_seeds)
{

    for(int i=sorting_size;i>=0;--i)
    {
        size_t index = // new index based on seed

        std::swap(temp_container[index],original[i]);
    }

    original.swap(temp_container);
}
```

std::swap is overloaded on std::string and should perform a move on the underlying string, but profiling seems to be showing the swap is performing a copy rather than a move, the report from perf shows

```sh
   - 56.95% std::swap<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >                                                                                                                                                   ▒
      - 51.14% std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::swap                                                                                                                         ▒
         - 17.71% std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_M_is_local                                                                                                               ▒
            - 8.77% std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_M_local_data                                                                                                           ▒
               - 7.49% std::pointer_traits<char const*>::pointer_to                                                                                                                                                          ▒
                  - 4.41% std::addressof<char const>                                                                                                                                                                         ▒
                       1.83% std::__addressof<char const>                                                                                                                                                                    ▒
                    0.94% std::__addressof<char const>                                                                                                                                                                       ▒
              3.48% std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_M_data                                                                                                                 ▒
              2.12% std::pointer_traits<char const*>::pointer_to                                                                                                                                                             ▒
         + 4.99% std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_M_set_length                                                                                                              ▒
         + 3.76% __gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<char>, char>::_S_on_swap                                                                                                                                           ▒
           3.62% std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::length                                                                                                                     ▒
           3.10% std::char_traits<char>::copy                                                                                                                                                                                ▒
           3.09% __memmove_avx_unaligned_erms                                                                                                                                                                                ▒
           2.59% std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_M_local_data                                                                                                              ▒
           1.48% std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_M_length                                                                                                                  ▒
           1.01% std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_M_get_allocator                                                                                                           ▒
           0.58% std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_M_data                                                                                                                    ▒
        1.21% std::char_traits<char>::copy                                                                                                                                                                                   ▒
        0.90% std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_M_set_length                                                                                                                 ▒
        0.90% std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::length                                                                                                                        ▒
        0.70% std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_M_is_local                                                                                                                   ▒
        0.69% __gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<char>, char>::_S_on_swap                                                                                                                                              ▒
        0.67% std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_M_get_allocator                                                                                                              ▒
        0.53% std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_M_length
```

I have tried to use the std::string swap method and forcing a move ie

```cpp
// tried this
temp_container[index].swap(original[i]);
// and this
temp_container[index] = std::move(original[i]);
```

But they made no difference benchmarking consistently shows the algorithm taking over 2secs to sort approximately 400k code strings.

Changing the vectors to use string_views initially gave much better results

```cpp
std::vector<std::string_view> temp_container(sorting_size+1,"");
for(auto &index_seed : all_seeds)
{

    for(int i=sorting_size;i>=0;--i)
    {
        size_t index = // new index based on seed
        // original is now also vector of string_view
        std::swap(temp_container[index],original[i]);
    }

    original.swap(temp_container);
}
```

Benchmarking shows the string_view version performing the same sort in under 1 sec.

However when i try compiling the algorithm with optimisation -O{1,2 or 3} the string_view version is two times slower than the std::string version.

Checking for cache misses

```sh
perf stat -e task-clock,cycles,instructions,cache-references,cache-misses ./CodeSortingAlgo
```

for the std::string non optimised version:

```sh
          2,756.98 msec task-clock                #    1.147 CPUs utilized          
     8,024,349,488      cycles                    #    2.911 GHz                    
    13,979,212,612      instructions              #    1.74  insn per cycle         
         3,560,486      cache-references          #    1.291 M/sec                  
         1,881,425      cache-misses              #   52.842 % of all cache refs    

       2.404464923 seconds time elapsed

       2.734367000 seconds user
       0.024020000 seconds sys
```

and for the string_view version:

```sh
          1,266.53 msec task-clock                #    1.354 CPUs utilized          
     3,586,135,363      cycles                    #    2.831 GHz                    
     4,780,766,035      instructions              #    1.33  insn per cycle         
         7,747,467      cache-references          #    6.117 M/sec                  
         6,172,017      cache-misses              #   79.665 % of all cache refs    

       0.935125202 seconds time elapsed

       1.243645000 seconds user
       0.023916000 seconds sys
```

Running the same for the version of algo compiled with -O2
std::string version:

```sh
            281.92 msec task-clock                #    1.214 CPUs utilized          
       794,130,273      cycles                    #    2.817 GHz                    
     1,166,108,846      instructions              #    1.47  insn per cycle         
        18,772,676      cache-references          #   66.589 M/sec                  
         3,797,519      cache-misses              #   20.229 % of all cache refs    

       0.232186807 seconds time elapsed

       0.258991000 seconds user
       0.023906000 seconds sys
```

string_view version

```sh
            393.30 msec task-clock                #    1.137 CPUs utilized          
     1,124,532,667      cycles                    #    2.859 GHz                    
       609,130,643      instructions              #    0.54  insn per cycle         
        12,675,992      cache-references          #   32.230 M/sec                  
         6,753,795      cache-misses              #   53.280 % of all cache refs    

       0.345989809 seconds time elapsed

       0.366555000 seconds user
       0.027590000 seconds sys
```

Why is std::swap and std::string::swap copying rather then moving, am i missing something? Have i read the perf report wrong?

Why is the cache performance of std::string_view so bad? Is it because rather than swapping the len and ptr its following the ptr then swapping?

Why is the optimiser not able to optimise the string_view version to the same level the string version.

compiler is gcc version 8.3.0

Comment: Have you considered the effect of "small string optimization" on your results? Are your strings (in general) quite short?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention in the original question that the average string length is 6 characters so the SSO would apply in the majority of cases. Digging deeper I found this post by Scott Meyers back 2012 (http://scottmeyers.blogspot.com/2012/04/stdstring-sso-and-move-semantics.html) stating that for SSO move is just as expensive as copies which could explain why the string is being copied. I'm still curious as to why the string_view version is so much faster (but still cache inefficient) in the unoptimised build, but so much slower in the optimised build.